# Parsing a table - tr.findall('td') - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, web-scraping

Does anyone know the error? the error displayed doesn't make much sense to me because I followed everything that the person was typing. And yes the website is a demo website for webscraping purposes.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36"}


response = requests.get("https://shubhamsayon.github.io/python/demo_html", headers = headers)
webpage = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")

for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
topic = "TOPIC: "
url = "URL: "
values = [data for data in tr.findall('td')]
for value in values:
print(topic, value.text)
topic = url
```

````
C:UsersAndyPycharmProjectspythonProjectvenvScriptspython.exe C:/Users/Andy/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:UsersAndyPycharmProjectspythonProjectmain.py", line 14, in
values = [data for data in tr.findall('td')]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1```
````

Comment: it should be `find_all` or `findAll` i guess

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36"}


response = requests.get("https://shubhamsayon.github.io/python/demo_html", headers = headers)
webpage = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")

for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    topic = "TOPIC: "
    url = "URL: "
    values = [data for data in tr.find_all('td')]
    for value in values:
        print(topic, value.text)
        topic = url
```

Output:

```
TOPIC:  __str__ vs __repr__ In Python
URL:  https://blog.finxter.com/python-__str__-vs-__repr__/
....
```

You can also try with `pandas` module to fetch table from url

```
    import pandas as pd
    df=pd.read_html("https://shubhamsayon.github.io/python/demo_html")[0]
    df
```

Output:

````
```
    TOPIC                                           LINK
0   __str__ vs __repr__ In Python                   https://blog.finxter.com/python-__str__-vs-__r...
1   How to Read a File Line-By-Line and Store Into. https://blog.finxter.com/how-to-read-a-file-li...
2   How To Convert a String To a List In Python?    https://blog.finxter.com/how-to-convert-a-stri...
3   How To Iterate Through Two Lists In Parallel?   https://blog.finxter.com/how-to-iterate-throug...
4   Python Scoping Rules â€“ A Simple Illustrated.   https://blog.finxter.com/python-scoping-rules-...
5   Flatten A List Of Lists In Python               https://blog.finxter.com/flatten-a-list-of-lis...
````

Comment: Which line would I put it in?

Comment: if above code you just need `pandas` if you dont have install it or my comment on your post you have to change here `[data for data in tr.find_all('td')]`

Comment: `C:\Users\Andy\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Andy/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py
  File "C:\Users\Andy\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 13
    topic: = "TOPIC: "
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
This is what it's saying now and I just installed pandas in pycharm it's saying the equals sign is an invalid syntax. I don't know if it comes out well in the format